# Components I used to draw a form won't appear after compile

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to create a chat program in java but I had a problem when I run the server form, that the components I used to draw won't appear.

this is the code I used in the run of the form :

```
public void run() {

                Server s = new Server();
                s.setVisible(true);

                // Etablir la connexion
                try
        {
            ServerSocket ecoute;
            ecoute = new ServerSocket(1111);
            Socket service = null;
            System.out.println("Serveur en attente d'un client !");
            while(true)
            {

                service = ecoute.accept();
                System.out.println("Client connécté !");
                DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(service.getInputStream());
                                s.jTextArea1.setText("Client dit : " + is.readUTF().toUpperCase());
                service.close();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
            }
```

Comment: Where is the code you use to draw the form?

Comment: @ChrisCooney I used netbeans to draw all the components inside my form, I didn't used any code to do that I just used the Design mode which allows me to drag and drop all those components, also this problem has something with this code I wrote because when I make it as a comment the form works perfectly.

Comment: Is this in a separate thread? and How do you call that thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said nothing happens when this code is ran. The presence of a `public void run()` method tells me that this is a thread, or at least a `Runnable`.

Because of the `while(true)`, if this thread is not started in the proper manner, it will not run independently; that is it will hold up the entire program.

Instead of calling `thread.run();`, call `thread.start();`. This will call the run method for you, after starting a new thread that will run in parallel to the main thread.

If this code is not in a thread, and you just used `public void run()` by chance, then it will still provide the same problem for you.

For more information, refer to the [Documentation on Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

Comment: I didn't used threads I just wrote the code inside the `public void run() method` which is generated by `Netbeans` automatically when I added a new `JFrame` to my project, this method is surrounded by  `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { //the public void run() method  });`

Comment: Yeah. then i'm still right. the while(true) part is what is holding up all of your code. You need to A:) Read up on Threads, then go and put the code you've got into it's own thread and B:) Mark my answer as correct because it's got all the information you need :)